# Why does Firebug say toFixed() is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I am using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.9.1. I am using the code below within a slider. (http://jqueryui.com/slider/)

I have a function that should test two values and depending on the difference between the two values reformat them (to the appropriate decimal place). If the difference is greater than 10, I will parse out the integer. If the difference is greater than 5, it should keep one decimal. Everything else, I will keep two decimals.

When I enter two values that have a difference that is ten or less, I use the toFixed() function.  And, in Firebug, I see an error:

```
TypeError: Low.toFixed is not a function
Low = Low.toFixed(2);
```

Is there something simple that I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var Low = $SliderValFrom.val(),
High = $SliderValTo.val();

// THE NUMBER IS VALID
if (isNaN(Low) == false && isNaN(High) == false) {
    Diff = High - Low;
if (Diff > 10) {
      Low = parseInt(Low);  
  High = parseInt(High);    
} else if (Diff > 5) {
       Low = Low.toFixed(1);
       High = High.toFixed(1);
} else {
       Low = Low.toFixed(2);
   High = High.toFixed(2);
}
}
```

Comment: I have same problem. but in local its work. when in live it show an error - TypeError: value.sell_price.toFixed is not a function

Answer (score 199, accepted):

`toFixed` isn't a method of non-numeric variable types. In other words, `Low` and `High` can't be fixed because when you get the value of something in Javascript, it automatically is set to a string type. Using `parseFloat()` (or `parseInt()` with a radix, if it's an integer) will allow you to convert different variable types to numbers which will enable the `toFixed()` function to work.

```
var Low  = parseFloat($SliderValFrom.val()),
    High = parseFloat($SliderValTo.val());
```

Comment: you forgot the parenthesis and quotes after $ sign, didnt you?

Comment: @AriWais `$SliderValFrom` is the variable name used by the OP, not a function

Comment: @jeremy you are right, I didn't pay attention to the original post... I just said to those that come looking straight to the solution its parseFloat($('slide').val())

Answer (score 106):

That is because `Low` is a string.

`.toFixed()` only works with a number.

---

Try doing:

```
Low = parseFloat(Low).toFixed(..);
```

Answer (score 30):

`Low` is a string.

`.toFixed()` only works with a number.

A simple way to overcome such problem is to use [type coercion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839):

```
Low = (Low*1).toFixed(..);
```

The multiplication by 1 forces to code to convert the string to number and doesn't change the value.

Comment: Save one character with (+Low).toFixed(..)     :P

Answer (score 6):

You need convert to number type:

```
(+Low).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`parseFloat()` will return `NaN` for empty string, why not using `Number()` function instead?

Values of other types can be converted to numbers using the `Number()` function.

```
parseFloat('').toFixed(2) // "NaN"
Number('').toFixed(2) // "0.00"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 2):

```
Low = Number(Low).toFixed(1);
```

add the `Number` function to convert `Low` into a number.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32042267)

Answer (score 0):

In a function, use as

```
render: function (args) {
    if (args.value != 0)
        return (parseFloat(args.value).toFixed(2));


},
```